# SQL Delete query INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to delete a row from a mysql table using php. I have two very basic tables. 'worksheet' and 'worksheet_labour'. Worksheet contains a field called job_ID and it has a field called WS_ID. Worksheet_Labour has a field called WS_ID and various other fields. I'm trying to delete all of the information within worksheet_labour for a particular job_ID that can be found in worksheet. This is what I've attempted so far but haven't had any luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
  if(isset($_GET["delete"]))
        {       
            $SQL = "DELETE FROM worksheet_labour INNER JOIN worksheet ON worksheet_labour.WS_ID = worksheet.WS_ID WHERE job_ID = '1234'";
            $resultset2 = mysql_query($SQL);
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Do you get an error message?  If so, which one?  If not, can you reproduce the problem at SQLFiddle.com with some example data?

Comment: [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) is your friend!

Comment: please explain the problem in detail so that people can help you , Improve the quality of your question and dump some errors you receive etc.

Comment: No error is received. When I check the table I created in PHP it simply is not deleted. I am able to delete entries using a simple delete sql query but using this INNER JOIN query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$SQL = "DELETE wl FROM worksheet_labour wl INNER JOIN worksheet w ON wl.WS_ID = w.WS_ID WHERE wl.job_ID = '1234'";
```